# C#: Stacking and moving transparent images

Tags: c#, .net, image, transparency, alpha

I'm fairly new to C# and the .NET library here, putting together a project to get myself more familiar with it.  What I'm trying to do is create a form with a background image (a "map") that has smaller images laid out on top of it ("figures", game pieces), which can be dragged around, and the whole thing can be zoomed in/out on.  It was all working beautifully until I tried to support transparent images.  It'd be great if I could support both images with transparent backgrounds (for the figures) and images with alpha layers (for map overlays, like weather effects or something).

I'm using PictureBox controls for all of my images, and I basically redraw the whole thing every time the map or a figure are zoomed in on or dragged (each time the mouse moves).  All I've done to "support" transparency is set figures' BackColor to Color.Transparent and set their parent to the map's PictureBox control.  The bug that results from this is:  The figures' transparency does work when I'm not touching the map, but when I'm dragging the map or a figure, it doesn't redraw the figure's image until I stop moving and it distorts the area (it looks like I'm clipping through walls in Doom) the image is over, even if the figure has no transparency.

Graphics, graphic files, etc are one of my weak areas, so I don't really know what's going on here.  If anyone has any ideas of how to fix this, or just to make it all work more smoothly (are there other image controls besides PictureBox I should look at?), that'd be appreciated.  Another small issue I know of is, if I were to overlap two transparent figures they'd cover each other up and I'd only see the background image, so maybe I'm just headed in the wrong direction here.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Adding my Render function below, it's called whenever any Map/Figure object is moved or created (MouseMove and MouseWheel events).

```
    //This method is attached to my "Map" class.
    //The "control" variables are PictureBoxes; I should probably have the Map/Figure classes extend PictureBox instead of that, though.
    public void Render()
    {
        this.control.Image = this.background;
        this.control.Width = (int)(this.background.Width * Scalar());
        this.control.Height = (int)(this.background.Height * Scalar());
        this.control.Location = new Point(offset.X, offset.Y);
        foreach (Figure figure in this.figures)
        {
            figure.control.Location = new Point(this.control.Location.X + System.Convert.ToInt32(figure.offset.X * Scalar()), this.control.Location.Y + System.Convert.ToInt32(figure.offset.Y * Scalar()));
            figure.control.Width = System.Convert.ToInt32(figure.base_size.Width * Scalar());
            figure.control.Height = System.Convert.ToInt32(figure.base_size.Height * Scalar());
        }
    }
```

Comment: for one, if you're creating a game you should be looking at XNA or the like. Otherwise if you're creating a basic Windows UI you should be using WPF. winforms is a really old technology that doesn't support anything and is not recommended for any new projects. It doesn't really support transparency and it's not hardware accelerated, therefore your resulting UI will probably suffer from constant flicker. And please post the relevant code you're working with instead of so much text

Comment: There's really not much to look at in the code, but I edited the post to add the main "rendering" function.  It just moves and scales PictureBoxes.  I don't think XNA's suited for this, but I'll give WPF a look this afternoon.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: if you can post a screenshot of what you need, maybe I can give you some jump-start in WPF to get that done.